# What are some examples of non-algebraic effects?

Tags: algebraic-effects

In [this (the only at time of writing) answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/42432/65167) to [How to tell if an effect is algebraic?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/42431/65167) informative positive examples are given.

But I suppose that's less complete without negative examples, to facilitate the intuition in "telling" algebraic vs non-algebraic effects apart.

I do think this can be a comment there, but don't have sufficient repu to do comment yet.